# print data from multicolumn listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, printing

i view all the data receive in multicolumn listbox. when i click print button, it will print out all the data review in listbox.

this is my code:

**1.** at first, the user will search keyword based on ID. then it will appear in multicolumn listview.this data is search in an xml file.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\Fatty\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\patient.xml");
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/main/patient");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string date = xn.OfType<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "Date").FirstChild.Value;
    string id = xn.OfType<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "ID").FirstChild.Value;
    if (date == cari)
    {
       listviewitem = new ListViewItem(date);
       listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
       this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
    }
       if (id == cari)
       {                    
           listviewitem = new ListViewItem(date);

           id = xn.OfType<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "ID").FirstChild.Value;
           listviewitem.SubItems.Add(id);

           string level = xn.OfType<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "Level").FirstChild.Value;
           listviewitem.SubItems.Add(level);

           string name = xn.OfType<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "Name").FirstChild.Value;                    
           listviewitem.SubItems.Add(name);
```

**2.** in the same method, i add up the print event button

```
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.printBut = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 381);
    this.Text = "Print Example";

    printBut.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;               
    printBut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 110);
    printBut.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
    printBut.TabIndex = 0;
    printBut.Text = "Print the file.";
    printBut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 40);
    printBut.Click += new System.EventHandler(printBut_Click);

    this.Controls.Add(printBut);
    //-------------print-----------------
```

**3.** this is printBut_click.

```
private void printBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader streamToPrint = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\Fatty\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\aboutREPCS.txt");

            try
            {
                printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
                pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);                       
                pd.Print();
            }
            finally
            {
                streamToPrint.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**4.** this is printPage event

```
// The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
           printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

        // Print each line of the file.
        while (count < linesPerPage &&
           ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count *
               printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
               leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        // If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (line != null)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

when i run this code, it appears `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
[image]

so, let me repeat the flow of this application.

```
User insert keyword.
If keyword match, view data from xml file into multicolumn listview.
printBut will print all the data view in listview.
```

Comment: Sara, write please where this exception appears? I mean, the place in code..

Comment: the first code and second is in the public Form3. is this what u asking?

Comment: Hmmm... no... I mean, when you go in debugger, which line of code throws an exdeption?

Comment: owh..it shows at the messagebox. i already edit my post.

Comment: If you declare the local variable streamToPrint in printBut_Click you can't use it in pd_PrintPage. Since you can compile this I guess you already have a field with the same name wich is never initialized and therefore your exception.